# Set viewmodel list field in controller conditionally

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, viewmodel

I'm currently in the process of trying to figure out a way to match data in a view model to data in a query and pass it conditionally to the view.

I have achieved this so far, however when I try to set a `ViewModel` value equal to a list in my query, I can't seem to find the right syntax to make it happy.

So far I have this:

```
public IEnumerable<QuestionViewModel> QuestionRead(int i)
{
    IEnumerable<Question> questions = _repository.GetQuestions(i);
    foreach (Question q in questions)
    {
        switch (q.Type)
        {
            case QuestionType.TextBasic:
               return questions.ToList().Select(question => 
               new QuestionViewModel 
               {
                   QuestionText = question.QuestionText,
                   QuestionId = question.QuestionId,
                   OrderIndex = question.OrderIndex + 1,
                   // ActualAnswer = question.Answer.TextAnswer.
                });
            case QuestionType.Multi:
                return questions.ToList().Select(question => 
                new QuestionViewModel
                {
                     QuestionText = question.QuestionText,
                     QuestionId = question.QuestionId,
                     OrderIndex = question.OrderIndex + 1,
                     // ActualAnswer = question.Answer.AnswerOptions.OptionText
                });
           }
     }

     return null;
}
```

When I get to the point of returning the `ViewModel` object called actual answer, which is a list, I'm trying to reach into the query and grab the list inside of the query.  The query returns the data from 3 tables, and `question.Answer.TextAnswer` is a string, but I want to add it to a list.  The reason for this is that I have another object called `MultiAnswer` that is a list.

Since all answers have to fit into one grid column, I want to set to the type to list so it can accomodate 1 or more items when displaying them.  I thought about doing a linq query `ActualAnswer = question.Answer.TextAnswer.ToList()`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `ActualAnswer = new List<string>(){question.Answer.TextAnswer};`

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it's saying System.Collections.Generic.List<char>  can't be converted into System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.   The viewmodel is type List<string> and the model itself is using a string (nvarchar) which I'm casting into a list, so I'm not sure where char is getting dervived from.

Comment: According to the error, it should be defined in <T> of your ActualAnswer list. Check it out.

Comment: If I change the type to List<char> in the viewmodel it works, but obviously this isn't what I'm after.  The model defines the property as a string.  The view model attempts to stuff that string into a list of type string.

Comment: There has to be something wrong with the initialization, but I can't help you further without any code samples.

Comment: public class Answer
    {
        // Primary Key
        public int AnswerId { get; set; } 

        public string TextAnswer { get; set; }

Comment: Model

 public class Answer 
    {
        // Primary Key
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }

        public string TextAnswer { get; set; }
}


ViewModel

    public class QuestionViewModel
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string ActualAnswer { get; set; }
    }
And the controller code is above in original comment.  When I change the value to string, I'm able to get data back but for some reason putting the string into a List<string> won't work.

Comment: I can see the TextAnswer is a string, but the problem is that the `ActualAnswer` list is actually a list of chars.

Comment: Before I changed it to just string:            public List<string> ActualAnswer { get; set; }

Comment: That's the way you told me it was, so it should be.